# How to programmatically correctly set drawable padding on button?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm having trouble setting the padding for a button to center the content (text + drawable).

Here is where I've gone so far:

```
Button done = new Button(this)
{
    Text = GetText((int)typeof(Resource.String).GetField("goalreached").GetValue(null))
};

    done.LayoutParameters = doneButtonParams;
    done.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.DoneGreenYakaButton);
    done.Typeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "fonts/Ubuntu-Medium.ttf");
    done.SetTextColor(Color.White);
    done.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Sp, 12);
    doneButtonParams.ColumnSpec = GridLayout.InvokeSpec(0, 2); // Setting colspan = 2
    var check = GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.ic_check_16px);
    check.SetBounds(0, 0, 32, 32); // Set the image size
    check.SetTint(Color.White); // Set the image color
    done.SetCompoundDrawables(null, null, check, null);
```

The result is this:

[image]

Obviously I want the check mark to be nearer the text and have the same padding as the one for the text on the left of the button.

What Am I missing here ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with xamarin for mobile development but the native Android way of doing this is setting the drawable padding on the button itself. [`setCompoundDrawablePadding(int)`](http://setCompoundDrawablePadding(int)) is the native method to accomplish adjusting the distance between text and the drawable.

**Ex:**

```
done.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
```

**Edit:** I realized you are looking to add padding on the outside of the checkmark, this would be accomplished with plain old [`setPadding(int, int, int, int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).

**Ex:**

```
setPadding(0,0,15,0);
```